# I don't know what's wrong with my code (rss reader with MWFeedParser)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, rss, xcode8

I am new to iOS. I was trying to build a simple rss reader using MWFeedParser. I get no build error, simulator pops up fine but then the simulator displays no RSS feeds but only the blank the tableView.
I can't think of what is wrong. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

```
//  FeedTableViewController.swift
//  RssReader

import UIKit
import MWFeedParser

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, MWFeedParserDelegate {

    var feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()

    func request() {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/Technology")
        //creating a feedparser object
        let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: url as URL!)
        feedParser?.delegate = self
        feedParser?.parse()

    }


    // MARK: - FEED PARSER DELEGATE

    func feedParserDidStart(_ parser: MWFeedParser!) {
        feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()
    }


    func feedParserDidFinish(_ parser: MWFeedParser!) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func feedParser(_ parser: MWFeedParser!, didParseFeedInfo info: MWFeedInfo!) {
        print(info)
        self.title = info.title
    }

    func feedParser(_ parser: MWFeedParser!, didParseFeedItem item: MWFeedItem!) {
        feedItems.append(item)
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        request()

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //height for rows
        return 100
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return the number of rows
        return feedItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem   
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.title

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure about how this library works but probably nothing holding on to your feedparser and it gets deallocated right after starting the request. Try using a property so that you hold a strong reference to the parser.

Comment: @Moxy Thank you for taking your time to reply. I have based this program entirely on a tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jootsUaCvAU], but carried it out my way. Could you please help elaborate on using properties holding strong reference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're code is not working because you are not respecting ATS. In other terms, your feed is in HTTP and not HTTPS.

You should see the following message if you open the console

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

You can solve this by setting an exception in your `info.plist`

[image: info.plist screenshot]

But Consider that Apple will not accept ATS exceptions in the near future.

Comment: Thank you for the help. You were absolutely right about the ATS error, I get exactly the same printed on my console. I made all the changes as you suggested but that didn't fix it. I am still getting the same ATS error. I cleaned the project and ran it again. I even tried 'AllowsArbitraryLoads' under ATSS and set it to 'YES', but it still didn't help. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried rewriting as you have show again but I don't know it doesn't work. In case it's relevant I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3. Any other ways we can fix this issue?

Comment: Ok, I finally got it working! The fix is Under the App Transport and Security Settings you add Allow Arbitrary Loads and set it's value to YES. Now Also add Exception Domains under the ATS Setting and under that add the website, for example here it's nytimes.com, and instead of dictionary set their Type as String. The NSExceptionAllowsinsecureHTTPLoads and NSIncludesSubdomains weren't necessary in my case. Hope this helps someone who comes across this issue. I would have loved to post a screen shot but seems I can't do it. And @Moxy thank you very much, your answer helped alot.

Comment: @JohnNapes I recommend you post and answer instead, comments are temporary. If the answer provided by SO user Moxy helps you, I encourage you to accept his answer and give him a upvote.

Comment: @Mauricio I am sorry, will do so. Gave him an upvote but seems you need some reputation for it to display. Thank you for the info.